# driver.find_elements() is returning empty list

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-crawler

Currently working on a crawler through python and selenium, target is https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Hotel_Review-g294265-d1845693-Reviews-The_Fullerton_Bay_Hotel_Singapore-Singapore.html#REVIEWS

Locating element by class_name returns empty list for some reason but works on 1 or 2 other elements. I've tried using XPath and Selectors but still returns empty list. Have attempted using parent class_names but don't work as well.

```
        #for review date of stay
        dateRows = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'teHYY _R Me S4 H3')
        for dates in dateRows:
            print(dates.text)

        #for review ratings
        ratingRows = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Hlmiy F1')
        for ratings in ratingRows:
            print(ratings.text)
```

Comment: Post a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following code, it can find 10 elements for each specified class, and clicknium supply recorder based on vscode, you can record to generate locator and don't need write xpath even.

```
from clicknium import clicknium as cc, locator

# only need for the first time
if not cc.chrome.extension.is_installed():
    cc.chrome.extension.install_or_update()

tab = cc.chrome.open("https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Hotel_Review-g294265-d1845693-Reviews-The_Fullerton_Bay_Hotel_Singapore-Singapore.html#REVIEWS")
elements = tab.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="teHYY _R Me S4 H3"]')
for elem in elements:
    print(elem.get_text())

elements = tab.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="Hlmiy F1"]')
for elem in elements:
    print(elem.get_property("innerHtml"))
```